# Hide zeros from kendo controls

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-combobox

Some of my kendo controls shows zero on load of the form. When I click the drop down to open, the actual values are seen. Could somebody tell me how to hide the zero value

[image]

Customer Name dropdown

```
  <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CustomerMasterDataId)

                 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                .DataTextField("CustomerNumberName")
                .DataValueField("CustomerMasterDataId")
                .Filter("contains")
                .MinLength(3)
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               // .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_CustomerData", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

                      .Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("RequestHeader_CustomerData", "Request")
                              .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                              .Data("GetSalesFilter");
                      }).ServerFiltering(true)
                                ).CascadeFrom("CountryCode").Filter("contains")

                   .Events(e =>
                     {
                        e.Change("onCustomerComboChange");
                     })
                        )
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does 0 shows only when the value of the specific Model's property is unset by the controller? If so you need to set placeholder property of the widget (default is unset) to " ".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Placeholder("Select...")`, which is displayed whenever no value is selected. Haven't used it in MVC wrapper thought.

More about [`placeholder`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-placeholder) for kendocombobox.